# winforms - placing an image over another image (stamp like) and save it

Tags: c#, image, winforms

i'm sorry if i'm going to cause some confusion with the question, as to it referring to something that might not be possible, but i'd like to, using winforms, create a form that would allow the user to load an image, select from the combobox some certificate level, then place its associated stamp over said image...

the issue i ran into is this: the loading works just fine, the selecting from the combobox (as i even know how to get specific images (let's call them 'stamps') from specific locations, and place them into a picturebox), and i can even save the first loaded image (let's call it 'pic1' for reference)... but i don't know how to program whatever it would be to place the 'stamps' over the 'pic1'... hell i could barely code the lines needed to what i already did, except for the formatting, and wouldn't have done it without help from 'stackoverflow'...

truth be told, i just recently finished some crappy 200 hours of coding in c# (and they weren't learned online, it was actually part of a course -_-...)

any ideas, help, suggestions or even a 'go back to what you were doing before starting to mess with programming', please?

thank you in advance. i'll leave here what i already have...

p.s.: i don't have much experience with OOP either, that's why the code below won't look like anything really optimized... :s

btw, the strings below inside the message boxes are in portuguese, because the user is my father, and it'd be easier for him, here in portugal, to have the form working in portuguese...

oh, and if you know any other language in which i should perhaps do this, please give that as feedback... many thanks :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // format form
        // TopMost gets the window at max resolution size; WindowsState already maximizes window at start;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        // format panel
        panPic.AutoSize = false;
        panPic.AutoScroll = true;

        // format picbox
        pbPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        pbPic.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    private void btLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // boolean tester
        bool test = false;
        // turn combobox and apply btn enabled;
        cbxCertificate.Enabled = true;
        btApply.Enabled = true;

        do
        {
            // open dialog box to upload picture;
            // instance OpenFileDialog class object 'dlg';
            OpenFileDialog dlgPic = new OpenFileDialog();
            // define object dialog title;
            dlgPic.Title = "Por favor selecione imagem a carregar";
            // define object dialog filter;
            dlgPic.Filter = "All Files|*.*";

            // if user decides object and presses 'OK';
            if (dlgPic.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // check if continue (probability of uploading incorrect image)
                DialogResult dlgConf = MessageBox.Show("Carregou a imagem: "
                    + dlgPic.SafeFileName.ToString() + "\nContinuar?", "Continuar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dlgConf == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    // show image and its location
                    txbLocation.Text = dlgPic.FileName.ToString();
                    pbPic.Image = Image.FromFile(dlgPic.FileName);

                    // check tester true to exit cycle
                    test = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // keep tester at false to continue inside the cycle;
                    test = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (test == false);
    }

    private void btApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbxCertificate.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            switch (cbxCertificate.SelectedText)
            {
                case "A+":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_a_mais.png
                    break;

                case "A":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_a.png
                    break;

                case "B":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_b.png
                    break;

                case "B-":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_b_menos.png
                    break;

                case "C":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_c.png
                    break;

                case "D":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_d.png
                    break;

                case "E":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_e.png
                    break;

                case "F":
                    // image location
                    // "Parent_Directory"\Certificados\cer_f.png
                    break;

            }// switch

            // enable save image btn
            btSave.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor selecione primeiro o tipo de certificado pretendido.");
        }
    }

    private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // confirm saving before actually opening the save dialog box
        DialogResult dlgConf = MessageBox.Show("Vai guardar a imagem editada. Continuar?", "Confirmar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        // observe validation
        if (dlgConf == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // save image from picture box to selected folder
            // instance save file dialog
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

            // default file name
            save.FileName = "EditedImage";

            // default file type
            save.DefaultExt = ".jpg";

            // default filter
            save.Filter = "Image (.jpg)|*.jpg";

            // restore current directory in case of closing before correct saving
            save.RestoreDirectory = true;

            // save file
            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = save.FileName;

                // define the using statement in case the object goes out of scope
                using (System.IO.FileStream fstream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                {
                    // define image saving ext and save object image into stream file selected path
                    pbPic.Image.Save(fstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    // close stream
                    fstream.Close();
                }
            }// if2
        }// if1
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Continue a edição por favor...");
        }// else1
    }
}// class Form
```

//// AFTER THE SITUATION WAS SOLVED ////

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    #region constructor
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // format form
        // TopMost gets the window at max resolution size; WindowsState already maximizes window at start;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        // format panel
        panPic.AutoSize = false;
        panPic.AutoScroll = true;

        // format picbox
        pbPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        pbPic.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    #endregion

    #region load_pic
    private void btLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // boolean tester
        bool test = false;
        // turn combobox and apply btn enabled;
        cbxCertificate.Enabled = true;
        btApply.Enabled = true;

        do
        {
            // open dialog box to upload picture;
            // instance OpenFileDialog class object 'dlg';
            OpenFileDialog dlgPic = new OpenFileDialog();
            // define object dialog title;
            dlgPic.Title = "Por favor selecione imagem a carregar";
            // define object dialog filter;
            dlgPic.Filter = "All Files|*.*";

            // if user decides object and presses 'OK';
            if (dlgPic.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // check if continue (probability of uploading incorrect image)
                DialogResult dlgConf = MessageBox.Show("Carregou a imagem: "
                    + dlgPic.SafeFileName.ToString() + "\nContinuar?", "Continuar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dlgConf == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    // show image and its location
                    txbLocation.Text = dlgPic.FileName.ToString();
                    pbPic.Image = Image.FromFile(dlgPic.FileName);

                    // check tester true to exit cycle
                    test = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // keep tester at false to continue inside the cycle;
                    test = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (test == false);
    }
    #endregion

    #region apply_stamp
    private void btApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // parent directory
        // original image to execute the method 'addStamp';
        // bitmap image to use in the method 'addStamp';
        // string to include the path of the stamp,
        // to be changed according to each case below (see switch);
        string parentDir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
        Image originalImage;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        string stampDir = "";

        if (cbxCertificate.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            // switch
            switch (cbxCertificate.SelectedItem.ToString())

            // note: whenever i need to switch over what's selected on a combobox,
            // use 'SelectedItem.ToString()';
            {
                case "A+":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\cer_a_mais.png";
                    break;

                case "A":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\cer_a.png";
                    break;

                case "B":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\cer_b.png";
                    break;

                case "B-":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\cer_b_menos.png";
                    break;

                case "C":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\cer_c.png";
                    break;

                case "D":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\cer_d.png";
                    break;

                case "E":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\cer_e.png";
                    break;

                case "F":
                    stampDir = parentDir + "\\Certificados\\Certificados\\cer_f.png";
                    break;

            }// switch

            // declare the originalImage being the image from the picture box (previously loaded);
            // execute the addStamp();
            // replace the image on the picture box with the edited one (bitmap);
            originalImage = pbPic.Image;
            bitmap = addStamp(originalImage, stampDir);
            pbPic.Image = bitmap;

            // enable save image btn
            btSave.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor selecione primeiro o tipo de certificado pretendido.");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region save_pic
    private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // confirm saving before actually opening the save dialog box
        DialogResult dlgConf = MessageBox.Show("Vai guardar a imagem editada. Continuar?", "Confirmar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        // observe validation
        if (dlgConf == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // save image from picture box to selected folder
            // instance save file dialog
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

            // default file name
            save.FileName = "EditedImage";

            // default file type
            save.DefaultExt = ".jpg";

            // default filter
            save.Filter = "Image (.jpg)|*.jpg";

            // restore current directory in case of closing before correct saving
            save.RestoreDirectory = true;

            // save file
            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = save.FileName;

                // define the using statement in case the object goes out of scope
                using (System.IO.FileStream fstream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                {
                    // define image saving ext and save object image into stream file selected path
                    pbPic.Image.Save(fstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    // close stream
                    fstream.Close();
                }
            }// if2
        }// if1
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Continue a edição por favor...");
        }// else1
    }
    #endregion

    #region methods
    public Bitmap addStamp(Image originalImage, String stampImagePath)
    {
        Image stampImage = Image.FromFile(stampImagePath);

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(originalImage);

        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        gr.DrawImage(stampImage, new Point(0, 0));

        return bitmap;

    }
    #endregion

}// class Form
```

thank you again to those who helped :)

Comment: TL;DR... Are you looking for watermarks? There are tons of question on SO (English and Português) about rendering over bitmap or saving image - so not really clear where you are stuck.

Comment: sorry about that... the problem is i don't really know much about programming, and can't understand wether what i need fits i to watermark category or not... maybe it's just so that I'm too noob and inexperienced, or that i haven't tried enough... sorry to make you lose your time answering... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, the code is very well documented, should not be so hard to understand it, you could try a step by step debug:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2927/Creating-a-Watermarked-Photograph-with-GDI-for-NET

As suggested by comments I wrote a little method which may help you:

```
public void addStamp(String originalImagePath, String stampImagePath,String outputPath)
        {   
            Image originalImage=Image.FromFile(originalImagePath);
            Image stampImage = Image.FromFile(stampImagePath);              

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(originalImage);

            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            gr.DrawImage(stampImage, new Point(0, 0));

            bitmap.Save(outputPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);    
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much for answering with such good examples... I'm not at a computer right now, but as soon as possible I'll test it to see if it fits into what i need...

Comment: thank you so much for your help... it worked out perfectly and the app is running very well... i'll post the complete code below in order for anyone who ever needs something like it can use it... thank you for not giving up on this noob :)